# Solution for knowledge base

Tags: database, knowledge-base

I'm going to create some knowledge base and want to seek some ready-made solutions before writing the own one from a scratch.

What solutions of knowledge base with following features or most of them could you suggest? I'm afraid there is no ready-made solution suiting all requirements, so any ideas and workarounds are appreciated.

In order of priority:

1. Write an article (knowledge base item) with rich formatting: headers, lists, images, videos etc.
2. Customizable design (via CSS or something else).
3. Commenting and liking articles.
4. Turn on or off some pre-defined sections (subheadings) in article: like See also, References, External links in Wikipedia. And edit the content of these sections.
5. Add tags to an article.
6. Put an article to a pre-defined category.
7. Set some properties for an article from a predefined value-parameter lists.

(Yes, article have tags, category and properties.)

8. Search articles by content and metadata (tag, category, properties).
9. Select tags instead of typing them manually each time.
10. Rename tags, categories, properties, sections.
11. Backup or export database.

Even more:

12. Organize tags and categories in a tree structure (like Evernote).
13. Add synonyms for tags, categories, properties.

Comment: There are certainly extensions to mediawiki to do everything except 12 & 13, for which there *may* be extensions.

Comment: Furthermore: Have you checked our [other quesstions tagged `knowledge-base`](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge-base)? Does none of those solutions apply for you?